# Вывести количество слов, букв в строке используя dictionary

Tags: python, словари, dict

Нужно вывести количество слов, букв в строке используя dictionary. 
Пример:

```
input:
a b c 
Output:
a 1 
b 1
c 1
Input:
to be or not to be
Output:
be 2 
to 2 
not 1
or 1
```

Вот мой вариант:

```
S = input()
D = dict()
for c in S:
     if c not in d:
         D[c] = 1
     else:
         D[c] += 1
for c in D:
     print(c,D[c])
```

Она работает но она выводит только буквы, а мне нужно чтобы оно выводило все что стоит после пробела. Нужно корректировать мой код или другой?

Comment: Нужно вывести слово и как часто оно встречается? Или вывести слово и количество букв в нем? Уточните вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'to be or not to be'
dict={x:a.count(x) for x in [x for x in set(a.split())]}
print(dict)   #{'not': 1, 'or': 1, 'be': 2, 'to': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
S = "to be or not to be"
D = dict()
for c in S.split():
    if c not in D:
        D[c] = 1
    else:
        D[c] += 1


for c in D:
    print(c,D[c])


to 2
not 1
or 1
be 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


data = 'to be or not to be'
dictionary = Counter()
for word in data.split():
    dictionary[word] += 1

print(dictionary)  # Counter({'to': 2, 'be': 2, 'or': 1, 'not': 1})
```

Comment: Тут можно проще и правильнее: `dictionary = Counter(data.split())`